# Multy Video Player using monotouch

Tags: iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmoviewcontroller

Here is the question:
Can a View in iPad to handle two different MpMoviePlayerView in the same Time
I have read that the moviePlayer is a singleton and I have to fix the observer with hard Code.
I am triying to do multiple Movie player in the same View??
Is it possible???
Any one have an idea???

Comment: Done Dimitar.I think that the idea is impossible with the restriction of apple store, Even changing the size of the player is not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MPMoviePlayerControllers` won't let you play back two videos simultaneously. Sorry! Whilst you can create two `MPMoviePlayer` objects if you try and play two streams back at the same time it will just break. This is mentioned in the documentation for that class, buried away somewhere.

Comment: Check this link my friend .
http://itunes.apple.com/app/fuze-meeting-hd/id389446884?mt=8#

Comment: You've not read my answer properly: I said `MPMoviePlayerControllers` won't let you play back videos simultaneously - not that it can't be done. It's actually a mentioned restriction in the Apple docs. So perhaps you should check this link, particularly the bit where it says "Although you can create multiple MPMoviePlayerController objects and present their views in your interface, only one movie player at a time can play its movie." - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Yes I saw this link, However There are some App that contains 2 movie players that Works simultanesouly.Did they use another component?

Comment: HEre is another app that shows multiple Videos at the same time
http://www.tuaw.com/2011/04/05/group-video-chat-coming-to-iphone-via-fring/

Comment: Yes, they do. You can implement it yourself using various C playback libraries, or use AVFoundation. But you cannot use Apple's stock video framework (MPMoviePlayerController) to do it.